# AGM absorbed glass mat battery charging

Tags: battery-charging

My agm battery is completely dead. I got it off of someone who said it was new and uncharged. Is there a way to check if it would accept charge? I brought it to Autozone and they were unable to charge it. it is deeply discharged. Should i hook up a 12v battery and a trickle charger to charge it, or would it risk explosion? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are proposing to connect a battery to a battery. That is a very bad idea. However, attaching a trickle charger to the discharged battery might be worthwhile. Keep in mind that it  is very possible that the battery is damaged beyond repair.

Comment: It is badly sulphated and needs work. It wont conduct much current unless it is possible to de-sulphate. But if too long since, it may be too late.  Inductive Pulse charge is the preferred method in parallel with a charger for an extended period.

Comment: The Battery University is a decent resource. Here's a link to the part about [battery sulfation](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/sulfation_and_how_to_prevent_it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is badly sulphated and needs work. It wont conduct much current unless it is possible to de-sulphate. But if too long since, it may be too late. Inductive Pulse charge is the preferred method in parallel with a charger for an extended period. – Tony Stewart. EE since '75 Mar 4 at 3:41

Comment: i got a 100$ ipc and it worked. it took days, but the batteries are desulfited. the heat generated by the ipc dissolved the sulphate surface and now the batteries are ok. not new, but ok